# Storing information of a dynamic C# asp.net application in a session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I'm currently building a dynamic C# ASP.NET application which is going to be used on mobile devices until such a time that we are able to create proper mobile apps for iOS and android devices.

The workflow is as follows: a user will log onto the system (Quality Management) and will have to answer questions, that are stored in a SQL database and will change daily.

As the user answers a question the database is being updated immediately, which obviously causes my page to be recreated due to the postback. To save time and prevent an unnecessary database calls to get all the questions again, on the initial page load I save all of the required data into a session.
The information saved within the session is then updated along with my database as the user answers a question and then is used to rebuild my webpage once the postback has occurred.

This has been working perfectly for me in the development environment but the amount of questions that a user will have to answer can range anywhere between 10 - 500 questions and we expect up to 300+ users using the system concurrently.

So **my questions are**:

1. Am I going about this all wrong?
2. What the impact on the server's performance will be when so many users start using it?
3. Is there a better way of storing all of this information to prevent me from having to make another call to the database to get all the questions and other related data?
4. Should i rather make another call to the database to get all the required information on postback?

I have read through this post [ASP.NET State Management Recommendations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z1hkazw7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) but im still a little confused and don't know which is the best route to take.

Thank you for your replies in advance.

Comment: Yes, you should use something that does a partial postback AJAX style, like MVC.  Then you could save the users answers in the background while they are doing the next question.

Comment: yoyo :D, I did greet everyone at the beginning of my question but for some reason it is not being displayed even after i have tried to update this post :'(

Comment: Greetings and signatures degrade the value of the question, so they are automatically removed.  And thank yous, while nice, detract from the Q&A style of the post.  Best to remove those also.

Comment: +1 for paqogomez for recommending MVC. Also, generally you should avoid using session states until you really desperately need it in some situation. In this situation, doing a full postback and querying the DB again is not that big of a deal at all.

Comment: Did you mean the _pool of questions_ is ~500, or a user, on a mobile device, will go through that many questions? Will there be a time limit for _each question_ ? Can the user stop and resume at any given point in time? IMHO, these will guide you to the appropriate _persistence_ model/s..Hth..

Comment: The user may stop at anytime, in rare cases we will need users to answer ~500 questions but most of the time they will answer between 10-50 questions and there is no time limit. Questions in the database will only be reset once a user has answered all of his current questions. could someone pls suggest a good MVC starting point.